# Make a Grid with Tkinter Rectangle

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to simulate a grid like what would be used for a game board using tkinter rectangles being drawn onto a canvas, however I am having trouble making a loop that does so correctly.

Pretty much I have a variable that contains a certain amount of rows for a grid and a variable for the amount of columns, and I need to create a grid of rectangles based off of those configurations which can change anytime the application is run, which is making it a bit tricky for me.

Anyways, I currently have a function to draw a rectangle to the screen like so:

```
def _place_empty_tiles(self):
        self._canvas.update()
        width = self._canvas.winfo_width()
        height = self._canvas.winfo_height()
        self.x = width / self._game.columns
        self.y = height / self._game.rows
        for i in range(self._game.columns):
            click_point = point.from_pixel(self.x, self.y, width, height)
            self._state.handle_click(click_point)
            self.x += 60

    def _redraw_game_pieces(self)->None:
        '''Delete and redraw all the  of game pieces'''
        self._canvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)
        canvas_width = self._canvas.winfo_width()
        canvas_height = self._canvas.winfo_height()

        for tile in self._state.all_tiles():
            center_x, center_y = tile.center().pixel(canvas_width, canvas_height)

            radius_x = tile.radius_frac() * canvas_width
            radius_y = tile.radius_frac() * canvas_height

            self._canvas.create_rectangle(
                center_x - radius_x, center_y - radius_y,
                center_x + radius_x, center_y + radius_y,
                fill = '#006000', outline = '#000000')
```

You may noticed I have some custom coordinate conversion methods going on to compensate for the screen re sizing. However, my problem is under the function `_place_empty_tiles(self)` in the for loop. Let's say the amount of columns is 4, it will currently print out on the canvas the following: [image]

However,

1. it is actually making a row, and
2. that is only one row.

How can I make it so I can create a grid with a similar style given the amount of rows and columns are stored in `self._game.columns` and `self._game.rows`?

UPDATE:
Tried basing it off [The tkinter  Knight's Tour Demo](http://pyinmyeye.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/tkinter-knights-tour-demo.html) I rewrote the function like so:

```
def _place_empty_tiles(self):
    self._canvas.update()
    width = self._canvas.winfo_width()
    height = self._canvas.winfo_height()
    for r in range(self._game.rows -1,-1,-1):
        for c in range(self._game.columns):
            click_point = point.from_pixel(c*30+4, r*30+4, c*30+30, r*30+30)
            self._state.handle_click(click_point)
    self._redraw_game_pieces()
```

which is close, but still getting some unexpected results:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The Tk demos include a [Knight's Tour](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/tcl/tcl-95/tk/tk/library/demos/knightstour.tcl) demo that draws a chessboard. Someone [converted it for tkinter](http://pyinmyeye.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/tkinter-knights-tour-demo.html) and you can examine the `_draw_board` function to see an example of how to create such a layout using canvas rectangles:

```
def draw_board(canvas):  
    # draw checkerboard
    for r in range(7, -1, -1):
        for c in range(8):
            if c&1 ^ r&1:
                fill = 'tan3'
                dfill = 'tan4'
            else:
                fill = 'bisque'
                dfill= 'bisque3'
            coords = (c*30+4, r*30+4, c*30+30, r*30+30)
            canvas.create_rectangle(coords, fill=fill, disabledfill=dfill,
                                    width=2, state='disabled')
```

Comment: I just tried it out, and it doesn't draw anything to the canvas.

Comment: It's not a complete program but if you use that along with `root = Tk(); canvas = Canvas(root); canvas.pack(fill="both"); draw_board(canvas); root.mainloop()` then it will certainly draw a chessboard pattern.

Comment: Okay, I managed to implemented and I updated my question, but I am still getting weird results. I am having trouble with the coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that draws a grid that fits the window as closely as possible. It is designed to redraw itself whenever the window resizes. If you don't want that behavior, you can hard-code the cell width and height.

The cells are stored in a dictionary indexed by row and column, to make it easy to reference each tile. Clicking on a tile will toggle it between blue and red. Note that when the window resizes it won't remember which cells were previously clicked on. That's easy to fix if you want.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=500, height=500, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="true")
        self.rows = 20
        self.columns = 20
        self.tiles = {}
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.redraw)
        self.status = tk.Label(self, anchor="w")
        self.status.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

    def redraw(self, event=None):
        self.canvas.delete("rect")
        cellwidth = int(self.canvas.winfo_width()/self.columns)
        cellheight = int(self.canvas.winfo_height()/self.columns)
        for column in range(self.columns):
            for row in range(self.rows):
                x1 = column*cellwidth
                y1 = row * cellheight
                x2 = x1 + cellwidth
                y2 = y1 + cellheight
                tile = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2, fill="blue", tags="rect")
                self.tiles[row,column] = tile
                self.canvas.tag_bind(tile, "<1>", lambda event, row=row, column=column: self.clicked(row, column))

    def clicked(self, row, column):
        tile = self.tiles[row,column]
        tile_color = self.canvas.itemcget(tile, "fill")
        new_color = "blue" if  tile_color == "red" else "red"
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(tile, fill=new_color)
        self.status.configure(text="you clicked on %s/%s" % (row, column))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```